# Правильно расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

*Это день рождения твоей дочери(,) а ты не знаешь, какой подарок она хочет?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, в Вашем сложном предложении запятые расставлены правильно.

Перед союзом **а** всегда ставится запятая. В этом правиле нет исключений. (Естественно, если предложение начинается с "А", то запятой нет.) Во всех остальных случаях можно смело ставить запятую.
Мне кажется, что интонация в этом предложении является повествовательной — просто констатируется факт незнания (знак вопроса не нужен).
**Это день рождения твоей дочери, а ты не знаешь, какой подарок она хочет.**

Если же необходимо поинтересоваться мнением родителя, то предложение, думаю, надо перестроить.
**Это день рождения твоей дочери. А ты знаешь, какой подарок она хочет?**

Comment: Вопросительная интонация вполне возможна. Она в этом случае отражает удивление: неужели ты не знаешь, что хочет твоя дочь на день рождения?

Comment: Это уже дело восприятия и сопровождающего контекста. Удивляться, думаю, можно и без вопросительной интонации. Вопрос-то, собственно, о запятой. Я на него ответила. Остальное — кто как видит. Теоретически можно и тире поставить. _Это день рождения твоей дочери — ты не знаешь, какой подарок она хочет?_

Comment: На мой взгляд, вопросительный характер высказывания (риторический вопрос) здесь _наиболее вероятен_, иначе такой текст стилистически небезупречен (не нужно "а"; "это" выглядит странно - будто человек _уже_ на дне рождения и спрашивает, что подарить дочери собеседника).

Answer (score 1):

Если это *риторический вопрос*, выражающий удивление или упрёк (Как, ты не знаешь, какой подарок нужен дочери?), то пунктуация **верна**. В этом случае условно повествовательная часть предложения по смыслу *подчинена* вопросу и эквивалентна выражению "*при том, что это день рождения твоей (собственной) дочери*". Действует формальное правило разделения запятой частей ССП, связанных противительным союзом "а" ( http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133 § 30, п.2).

С меньшей вероятностью можно предположить здесь другой контекст и смысл: знакомый собеседника интересуется, что подарить его дочери. Тогда первая часть - утверждение, а вторая - вопрос, требующий ответа. В этом случае нужно либо разделить предложение на два (поставив точку перед вопросом), либо поставить *тире* между его частями. При этом оказывается ненужным союз "а", а местоимение "это" становится не вполне естественным (вместо него лучше "сегодня" и т. п.).

Comment: Это был упрёк. Просто я не знал как правильнее будет: с запятой или разделить.  Спасибо за ответ!